# Scifi movie from 70s, 80s - Humanoid on Earth in search for the key to his spaceship (ship looks like a dragon)

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

The movie is about the search for an ancient artifact. At the beginning, the movie looks like it's a crime piece about a criminal band that is looking for some priceless relics.
Later, it seems that band is lead by an alien. Near the end of the movie, they find the artifact. The alien leader is badly wounded, but is able to activate the artifact.

It appears that the artifact is a key that enables (activates) an alien spaceship. The spaceship is buried in the mountain somewhere in China. It roars to life and looks like a dragon from legends. Then, it disappears (seems to be teleported to some distant world).

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0811671/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl?

Comment: Here dragon-spacecraft is a big one. It slowly emerges from the mountain (or rock), and looks like a big dragon, made of metal. Then it turns into a fire and ... gone ! Key is kind of sphere or so, and serves like a remote for the dragon-spacecraft.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eventually found it: "The Legend of Wisely" (1987)

[IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090302/?ref_=kw_li_tt), [wiki:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Wisely)

> Wisely, the famous writer/adventurer, is tricked by his friend (played
> by Teddy Robin, the film's director) into helping him steal the dragon
> pearl. Samuel Hui plays Wisely in this big budget Hong Kong movie,
> with production units filming some scenes by the Great Pyramids, and
> many scenes in Nepal. There are car chases and crashes, chases by
> horsemen and plenty of fights along the way. The Legend of Wisely is a
> live action comic book. A lot of effort went into making this movie,
> and it shows as Wisely goes from one hazard to another, a Hong Kong
> version of Indiana Jones.

Movie itself: https://vikv.net/watch/the-legend-of-wisely-1987/

[image]

[image]