# Movie involving a crashed/landed alien craft in an icy cavern

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

I only remember one scene from this movie. A guy finds a black spacecraft in a icy cavern. I'm pretty sure there was another bad guy seeking the ship in the mountain.

This would have been a movie (or maybe a TV show), somewhere from late 80s to mid 90s. not a comedy.

For some reason my brain links this to [*The Golden Child*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Child) (and Eddie Murphy) or one of the [*Witch Mountain* films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_Mountain_(franchise)) but he definitely isn't either of those.

**Edit:** Pretty sure it is [*Legend of Wisely*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Wisely), a 1987 Hong Kong movie. Thanks again.

Comment: Probably not *[The Thing from Another World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5dwbZKd64Y)*!

Comment: Probably not [*The Ice Warriors*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8p4vWW9Ddk&t=1s)

Comment: Rather makes me think of The X-Files movie, big alien ship in Antarctica

Comment: Probably not [*The X-Files movie*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QUAEFiNatE)

Comment: Probably not [*Quatermass and the Pit*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhFM-8wiDrw)

Comment: Probably same movie as in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267996/early-90s-or-late-80s-tv-series-involving-a-spaceship-or-alien-vessel-hidden-ins

Comment: "Guyver - Dark Hero" (1994) has the good guy and the bad guy slug it out over a spaceship in a cavern, but you probably would have remembered insectoid looking exoskeletons.

Comment: Are you sure you're not slightly misremembering ***Alien (1979)*** itself?

Comment: Probably not Man of Steel (2013) (Superman) with Henry Cavill as dates wrong, matches on "guy finds a spacecraft in an icy cavern".

Comment: If it is *Legend of Wisely*, you should click the checkmark at top left of that answer below instead of editing your title with "[SOLVED]".

Comment: Please note that closing a question as a duplicate is not a criticism of the question, but it is good bookkeeping.  In any case, if you do come back, please *accept* the answer by clicking the checkmark below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 12):

Could be [**The Flying Saucer**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0042469/), [Full movie on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUtbvrmMO6w), although it is from 1950 =)

"A guy finds a black spacecraft in an icy cavern":
[image]

Mountains:
[image]

The cave:
[image]

**Plot**

> American Intelligence officials learn that Soviet spies have begun
> exploring a remote region of the Alaskan Territory in search of
> answers to the worldwide reports of "flying saucers". A wealthy
> American playboy, Mike Trent (Mikel Conrad), who was raised in that
> remote region, is recruited by intelligence officer Hank Thorn
> (Russell Hicks) to assist a Secret Service agent in exploring that
> area to discover what the Soviets may have found.
>
> To his pleasant surprise, Mike discovers the agent is an attractive
> woman named Vee Langley (Pat Garrison). They set off together and
> slowly become mutually attracted to each other. Their cover story is
> that Mike is suffering from a nervous breakdown and she is his private
> nurse. At Mike's family's wilderness lodge, they are met by a
> foreign-accented caretaker named Hans (Hantz von Teuffen), new to the
> job.
>
> Mike is very skeptical of the flying saucer reports until he spots one
> flying over the lodge. Assorted complications ensue until Mike and Vee
> finally discover that **Hans is one of the Soviet agents who is trying
> to acquire the flying saucer**. It turns out that the saucer is an
> invention of American scientist Dr. Lawton (Roy Engel). But Turner
> (Denver Pyle), Lawton's assistant, is a communist sympathizer and has
> other ideas: he tries to make a deal to sell the saucer to the Soviets
> for one million dollars.
>
> Mike's trip to Juneau to see old friends, including Matt Mitchell
> (Frank Darrien), is ill-advised. When Vee tracks him down, he is in
> the company of a bar girl, named Nanette (Virginia Hewitt). **Matt gets
> mixed up with the Soviet agents who are trying to obtain control of
> the saucer**. When he tries to strike a bargain with ring leader Colonel
> Marikoff (Lester Sharpe), at the spy's headquarters, Matt is knocked
> unconscious.
>
> He is able to escape and seeks out Mike, but they are attacked by the
> Soviets, who kill Matt. Before he dies, however, Matt reveals the
> location of the saucer: Twin Lakes. Mike rents an aircraft and flies
> to where the saucer is hidden at an isolated cabin. After flying back
> to his lodge, he tries to find Vee, who has tried to spirit Lawton
> away. The trio are captured by the turncoat Taylor and a group of
> Soviet agents. The Soviets lead their prisoners **through a secret
> tunnel hidden under the glacier**. An avalanche begins and wipes them
> out. Mike, Vee, and Lawton escape the tunnel just in time to see
> Turner fly off in the saucer. It suddenly explodes in mid-air, due to
> a time bomb that Lawton had planted on board for such an eventuality.
> Their mission now accomplished, Mike and Vee embrace and kiss.

Answer (score 11):

It could be the [*Legend of Wisely*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Wisely), a 1987 Hong Kong movie.

The trailer shows people in an icy cavern with a ship (large technical object) moving in ice as it launches.

The guy dressed in black tight suit seen falling as the ice bridge collapses is the main "bad guy" if I remember correctly. Not sure if the spaceship was black anymore (in the trailer it is covered by ice and snow), but I remember afterwards it was flying in the night sky, leaving Earth.

[image]

Comment: Actually they were looking for the pearl, that was a key to the ship.
And the ship itself looks like a dragon, we have a topic for that movie: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226778/scifi-movie-from-70s-80s-humanoid-on-earth-in-search-for-the-key-to-his-space/226811

Comment: Just watched some parts of this and 99% sure it is. Thanks so very much.

Comment: @AdamCrisp If this is the answer you should accept it by clicking on the grey checkmark at the upper-left corner of the answer underneath the voting arrows.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be John Carpenter's [The Thing (1982)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084787/)? It's set in Antartica and involves a spaceship that's found in the ice (and is arguably black). It looks like this:

[image]

It's definitely not a comedy - it's a horror movie about an alien shapeshifter that can take over dead bodies. I don't *think* there's a bad guy seeking the spaceship though, unless you count the alien itself.

Comment: Not *intentionally* a comedy, I think you mean

Comment: Well, comedy is intensely subjective. I get belly laughs from a number of "not a comedy" movies.