# Old sci-fi movie which i think was ending in old desert temple with a "pool" of water in which was sphere

Tags: story-identification, movie

In the sphere were holes that started glowing white at the end after one of the main characters get inside it.

I think two groups fight to get it. One may be some Victoria-era-dressed British explorers with locals that worshipped it.

Comment: You'd tagged this as 'time travel'. Is there any time travel here?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Its either time or space travel that is the sphere doing at the end i think.

Comment: I think i saw it around like 2005 its surely older from like 70-80s. 90s at total top. From what i remember it did have some alien/god like subtext something like contact maybe ? I also believe the final scene was with two main characters trying to get into the sphere but only one surviving while the other is attacked by the locals with spears i think it was man and woman.

Comment: It should be from desert either African one or Middle East.

Comment: Could it be [Legend Of Wisely](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qos784qrrME)?
(https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226778/scifi-movie-from-70s-80s-humanoid-on-earth-in-search-for-the-key-to-his-space/226811)

Comment: Its kinda similar especialy the start but i think the main cast was white and there werent cars in the movie.

Answer (score 8):

I think this could be a [Secret of the Sahara](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092448/) 1988 Italian TV miniseries, featuring Michael York, Ben Kingsley, Andie MacDowell, about

> the quest of archaeologist Desmond Jordan to discover the location of the legendary Talking Mountain of the Sahara desert, and find the secret that it hides

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9iWpZMxJA0)(?) where spherical object partially submerged in the pool is visible, also at different time in the trailer there is glowing orb present.

From what I recall seen the series about 30 years ago, it was about ancient crashed alien spacecraft, a particular Sahara people tribe being the descendants of the aliens, protecting it.

There seems to be complete series on Youtube (found the Polish dub version), but due to possible copyright issues, I won't post the link here.

Comment: OHHHHH YES!!!! I think that could be actually it ! Thank you ! Thanky you so much m8 it really looks like what i remeber ! Thank you ! Was searching this for eternity.

Comment: I even found it in my language online wtf !!! Going to watch it rn! Thanks again !